# NumberFormatter issue for large number

Tags: swift, numberformatter

I try this code for converting string to number and vic versa.
this code must print the same outputs. but its output is not correct.
can any one help me?

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")


if let r1 = formatter.number(from: "10123456789012349") , let r2 = formatter.string(from:r1){

     print(r1) // output = 10123456789012349
     print(r2) // output = 10123456789012348
}
```

also this code has same problem

```
print(formatter.string(from:NSNumber(value: 10123456789012349)))
//output is 10123456789012348
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NumberFormatter` produces an `Int64` when it parses the string in the example. This type can exactly represent the numeric value. But the formatter uses double arithmetic even for 64 bit integers to compute the string representation of a number. A double can represent approximately 16 or 17 decimal digits at most. This leads to the suprising different results.

You can avoid this by using `Decimal`s:

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true

let r1 = formatter.number(from: "10123456789012349")
let r2 = formatter.string(from: r1!)
print(r1!) // 10123456789012349
print(r2!) // 10123456789012349
```

EDIT: Using `Decimal`s for formatting is sufficient for exact results:

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let d1 = 10123456789012349 as Decimal

print(formatter.string(from: d1 as NSNumber)!)
```

Comment: `let r1 = formatter.string(from: 10123456789012349 as NSNumber), let r2 = formatter.number(from: r1)` both are 10123456789012348

Comment: @Adrian Bobrowski: Yes, because the formatter in the first statement uses double arithmetic.

Comment: how can i handle it? 123456789012345678901234