# NumberFormatter and unsigned with UInt64.max

Tags: swift, uint64, numberformatter

I'm trying to create a string representing `UInt64.max` using `NumberFormatter`. Here's the code:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.positiveFormat = "# ##0.#########"
formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 20
formatter.usesSignificantDigits = false
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 20
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false
// formatter.roundingMode = .halfUp
let text1 = formatter.string(for: NSNumber(value: Int64.max))
let text2 = formatter.string(for: NSNumber(value: UInt64.max))

print(text1)
print(text2)
```

which prints:

> Optional("9,223,372,036,854,780,000")
> Optional("-1")

but should print

> Optional("9223372036854775807")
> Optional("18,446,744,073,709,551,615")

It looks like `NSNumber` is rounding `Int64` and isn't taking the `UIn64`. The obj-c version of `NSNumberFormatter` works fine.

Am I missing something or is there a problem with `NumberFormatter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, found a solution:

```
let text2 = formatter.string(for: Decimal(UInt64.max))
print(text2)
```

This prints `Optional("18,446,744,073,709,600,000")`

[Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520703/7877857)

Comment: Very nice. My tinkering spirit did not go that far! Thanks!

Comment: Note that UInt.max value is `"18,446,744,073,709,551,615"` not `"18,446,744,073,709,600,000"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [formatted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/3796456-formatted) `Generic Instance Method` and specify `number` style:

**iOS15+ • Xcode 13**

```
let decimal1 = Decimal(Int64.max)
let decimal2 = Decimal(UInt64.max)

let text1 = decimal1.formatted(.number)
let text2 = decimal2.formatted(.number)

print(text1)
print(text2)
```

---

This will print

> 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
> 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Comment: Have admit its new to me but found some details that make it worth wild looking into it. [More details here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3767271-formatted) Thank!

Comment: @Phantom59 Sorry I posted the wrong link. Unfortunately the documentation is really poor. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/3796456-formatted