# How is an integer formatted to a String with comma separators for thousands in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, formatting, foundation

I want to be able to convert any integer, I'm only using Int and UInt16 at the moment, into a String with a separator to group the thousands, if any.  For example the value 12345 as input would output the string "12,345".

I found this solution but it fails, returning "12345".

```
import Foundation

func readable<T: BinaryInteger>(_ value: T) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = Locale.current.groupingSeparator ?? ","
    if let formattedValue = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(nonretainedObject: value)) {
        return formattedValue
    } else {
        return "\(value)"
    }
}
```

I had first found a variation of the argument for NSNumber but that does not compile so I suspect that the argument for NSNumber is not correct.

How do I fix this?

```
NSNumber(value: value) // snippet does not compile.
```

Edit: The answer is found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999137/75062
but it didn't show on my searches ...

Comment: `numberFormatter.string(for: value)`.

Comment: @HangarRash this will suffer some issues when the value is too large https://stackoverflow.com/q/72148946/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Interesting. Is the problem the use of `NumberFormatter` versus using the newer `formatted()` or is the issue with my suggestion to use the `string(for:)` method from `Formatter`?

Comment: I believe the issue is related to the older NumberFormatter not supporting 64 bit unsigned integers. `string(for:Any)` is declared under Formatter not NumberFormatter

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.5**

```
Int64(123457890).formatted() // "123,457,890"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about the (unknown to me) .formatted() method.  In fact I don't think you even need the Int64 bit, as you can simply create a String by writing let str = 123457890.formatted().  This is in Swift 5.9 if that makes any difference.